# Crop a div element (select an area and get coordinates (x,y,w,h)) and use them to create another div

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to crop a div element (visually selecting an area) and get its coordinates (x,y,w,h) relative to parent? (In order to use them to create another div and place it as a sibling node?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record the mouse down coordinates and when the mouse is released, append a child to the content element (the content element must be in relative or absolute position to count as a the position container for its children).

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");

let contentMouse = null;

content.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
  contentMouse = {
    x: event.offsetX,
    y: event.offsetY
  };
});

content.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
  contentMouse = null;
});

content.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
  if(contentMouse == null)
    return;
    
  let x = event.offsetX;
  let y = event.offsetY;
    
  if(x < contentMouse.x) {
    x = contentMouse.x;
    contentMouse.x = event.offsetX;
  }

  if(y < contentMouse.y) {
    y = contentMouse.y;
    contentMouse.y = event.offsetY;
  }
    
  const width = x - contentMouse.x;
  const height = y - contentMouse.y;

  const element = document.createElement("div");
  element.className = "selection";
  
  element.style.width = `${width}px`;
  element.style.height = `${height}px`;
  
  element.style.left = `${contentMouse.x}px`;
  element.style.top = `${contentMouse.y}px`;
  
  content.append(element);
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 320px;
  
  background: red;
  
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  
  left: 60px;
  top: 20px;
  
  width: 400px;
  height: 230px;
  
  background: green;
}

.selection {
  position: absolute;
  
  background: blue;
  
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
  
  </div>
</div>
```